# Returning Three Dimensional Associative Arrays with PHP

Tags: php

I suppose I am a noob with PHP so apologies if I sound dumb, but, I do have a troubling dilemma, I have spent the last six hours plus scouring Google for any hints and found none so here I am on the SO forum looking for some 'pointers' in the right direction.

I have an issue with returning 3DAA's from a function in a class to other parts of my code and no matter what I try I'm getting a null value back, according to the error log anyway, but when I run this code separately from the framework, in a single file using the same declarations it miraculously starts working and echos the specified part of the array to the screen wahey, but I don't know why it suddenly works nor why it won't work in the framework and supplies a null value.

I was wondering if anyone out there has experienced such weird errors with returning 3DAA's and if so, how they got around it. If you want to see the code ask and I'll post it.

```
<?php
 class Core {
  public function GetConfiguration() {
  $configuration = array(
   "cobalt" => array(
    "name" => 'Cobalt',
    "version" => '1.0.7',
    "directory" => array(
     "root" => 'application',
     "modules" => 'application/modules',
     "html" => 'application/html'
     )
    ),
    "application" => array(
     "name" => 'Cardinal Technologies',
     "version" => '1.0.2',
     "server" => 'http://localhost',
     "seo" => array(
      "copyright" => 'Ida Boustead',
      "description" => 'Welcome to Cardinal Technologies, here at Cardinal Technologies we pride ourselves in providing the best possible customer service whether you need a repair or upgrade for a computer, android phone or tablet, even alarms and CCTV',
      "keywords" => 'computer repair,computer upgrade,computer upgrades,android phone repair,phone repair,android tablet repair,tablet repair,alarms,cctv,network installation,network install',
      "robots" => 'index,follow'
      )
     )
    );
    return $configuration;
   }
   public function LoadModule($module) {
    require_once 'application/modules/' . $module . '.class.php';
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Hope this helps.

I'm calling it like this.

```
require_once 'application/Core.class.php';
$core = new Core();
$configuration = $core->GetConfiguration();
```

and getting an array value like this.

```
$dir = $configuration['cobalt']['directory']['html'];
```

the prior is a snippet from a larger file but this is what relates to that function.

I get `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dir` in the log which is what led me to believe the function was the problem.

If I echo `$dir` it echos `application/html` which is what it's supposed to, but it is not usable for anything other than echo which is pointless to me as I need that value to make other parts of the framework work.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code demonstrating the issue you're encountering.

Comment: Please share the code you have done, so people can understand what you have done so far and can answer you right way.

Comment: Please add your input code and what you want in output code.explain in proper way

Comment: Your function as it stands is fine. How are you using it? The solution will be nothing to do with what you are returning and everything to do with how you're calling it.

Comment: Error messages will indicate in which line of the code the error occurs. What is on that line?

Comment: The declaration for `$dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Right it was me being a dumb dumb, I put the declarations in the wrong place, outside of the class and it did not like it.

I moved them to inside of each function that stalled the code and it fixed that issue. Thanks anyway.